# Get row touched UILabel for cell in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uilabel

Colleagues, I have a problem with getting of row when I pressed on `UILabel` in cell in `UITableView`.
So, I have

```
class CellOfFirstTableView: UITableViewCell
```

where I have

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelChangeSomething: UILabel!
```

with that cell I work in

```
class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController
```

so I'd like to get row for pressed `UILabel`, but I don't know how to do it. My code for cell and action of press:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath) as! CellOfFirstTableView
    let list = sortOfSomething(id: id_something)[indexPath.row]

    //tapRecognizer
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FirstTableViewController.tapFunction))
    cell.labelChangeSomething.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.labelChangeSomething.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    return cell
}
```

and function for action:

```
func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

print("Hello world")

  }
```

I'd like to get row of pressed `UILabel` (when I press in `UILabel` I see "Hello world", but I want see row in what `UILabel` is located. I can get row of pressed cell, but user may press only `UILabel` and don't press part's of cell where `UILabel` not active.
Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Can you just check selection of cell?

Comment: Why you are not using didSelectRow method?

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov no, because cell not active when user pressed in `UILabel`

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya because I want get row, but not after pressed cell, and user pressed `UILabel `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)You can make use of tag property of `UIView`. Just add tag to the `labelChangeSomething` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath) as! CellOfFirstTableView
    let list = sortOfSomething(id: id_something)[indexPath.row]

    //tapRecognizer
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FirstTableViewController.tapFunction))
    cell.labelChangeSomething.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.labelChangeSomething.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
     //here added tag
    cell.labelChangeSomething.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

2) update your selector method like below

```
func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

if let label = sender.view as? UILabel {
   //print label tag here == indexpath.row
   print("row = \(label.tag)")
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `UITapGestureRecognizer` when you tap on a label in a cell you are clicking on the cell, you need to call

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

`TableViewDelegate` and write this code in it.

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath) as? CellOfFirstTableView
```

Comment: my UILabel is active (in future) and UILabel will reload cell, so I need in `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: You do not have a good approach instead of making your `UILabel` tappable insert a `UIButton` on top of your `UILabel` in the cell. so when the user taps on the label area of the cell the action of the button would be called.